# Function couldn't been resolved

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I have a problem with my C++ code. It says that the  all the functions starting with isPerfectRec() couldn't be resolved...Why? I tried a lot of things but apparently they don't work. I have a lot of assigments like to verify if the binary search tree is perfect, to find the second largest element in a binary search tree and so on..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
template<typename T> class BinarySearchTree {
    public:
        BinarySearchTree<T> *root, *left_son, *right_son, *parent;
        T *pinfo;

        BinarySearchTree() {
            left_son = right_son = NULL;
            root = this;
            pinfo = NULL;
        }

        void setInfo(T info) {
            pinfo = new T;
            *pinfo = info;
        }

        void insert(T x) {
            if (pinfo == NULL)
                setInfo(x);
            else
                insert_rec(x);
        }


        bool isPerfectRec(BinarySearchTree *root, int d, int level = 0)
        {
            // An empty tree is perfect
            if (*root == NULL)
                return true;

            // If leaf node, then its depth must be same as
            // depth of all other leaves.
            if (*root->left_son == NULL && root->*right_son == NULL)
                return (d == level+1);

            // If internal node and one child is empty
            if (root->*left_son == NULL || root->*right_son == NULL)
                return false;

            // Left and right subtrees must be perfect.
            return isPerfectRec(root->*left_son, d, level+1) &&
                   isPerfectRec(root->*right_son, d, level+1);
        }
        // Wrapper over isPerfectRec()
        bool isPerfect(BinarySearchTree *root)
        {
           int d = findADepth(root);
           return isPerfectRec(root, d);
        }
        int findADepth(BinarySearchTree *node)
        {
           int d = 0;
           while (node != NULL)
           {
              d++;
              node = node->left_son;
           }
           return d;
        }

        // A function to find 2nd largest element in a given tree.
        void secondLargestUtil(BinarySearchTree *root, int &c)
        {
            // Base cases, the second condition is important to
            // avoid unnecessary recursive calls
            if (root == NULL || c >= 2)
                return;

            // Follow reverse inorder traversal so that the
            // largest element is visited first
            secondLargestUtil(root->right_son, c);

            // Increment count of visited nodes
            c++;

            // If c becomes k now, then this is the 2nd largest
            if (c == 2)
            {
                std::cout << "2nd largest element is "
                     << root->pinfo;
                printf("\n___\n");
                return;
            }

            // Recur for left subtree
            secondLargestUtil(root->left_son, c);
        }
        void secondLargest(BinarySearchTree *root)
        {
            // Initialize count of nodes visited as 0
            int c = 0;

            // Note that c is passed by reference
            secondLargestUtil(root, c);
        }
        bool hasOnlyOneChild(int pre[], int size)
        {
            int nextDiff, lastDiff;

            for (int i=0; i<size-1; i++)
            {
                nextDiff = pre[i] - pre[i+1];
                lastDiff = pre[i] - pre[size-1];
                if (nextDiff*lastDiff < 0)
                    return false;;
            }
            return true;
        }

        BinarySearchTree * readListInter(){
            BinarySearchTree* root = NULL;//returning object
            BinarySearchTree* temp;
            BinarySearchTree* input;//new node to add
            int x;

            std::cout << "enter number (>0 to stop): ";
            std::cin >> x;
            while(x>=0){
                input = BinarySearchTree(x);
                if(root == NULL){//if root is empty
                    root = input;
                    temp = root;//temp is use to store value for compare
                }
                else{
                    temp = root; //for each new addition, must start at root to find correct spot
                    while(input != NULL){
                        if( x < temp->pinfo){//if smaller x to add to left
                            if(temp->left_son == NULL){//left is empty
                                temp->left_son = input;
                                input = NULL;//new node added, exit the loop
                            }
                            else{//if not empty set temp to subtree
                                temp = temp->left_son;//need to move left from the current position
                            }
                        }
                        else{//otherwise x add to right
                            if(temp->right_son == NULL){//right is empty
                                temp->right_son = input;
                                input = NULL;//new node added, exit the loop
                            }
                            else{
                                temp = temp->right_son;//need to move right from the current position
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                std::cin >> x;
            }
            return root;
        }
};

int main() {
    BinarySearchTree<int> *r = new BinarySearchTree<int>;
    BinarySearchTree<int> *r1 = new BinarySearchTree<int>;
    BinarySearchTree<int> *p = new BinarySearchTree<int>;
       p = readListInter();
    r->insert(6);
    r->insert(8);
    r->insert(1);
    r->insert(9);
    r->insert(10);
    r->insert(4);
    r->insert(13);
    r->insert(12);

    printf("\n___\n");
       r1->insert(6);
       r1->insert(8);
       r1->insert(1);
       r1->insert(9);
       r1->insert(10);
       r1->insert(4);
       r1->insert(13);
       r1->insert(12);

           printf("\n___\n");

     r->isPerfect(r);
     int pre[] = {8, 3, 5, 7, 6};
         int size = sizeof(pre)/sizeof(pre[0]);
         if (hasOnlyOneChild(pre, size) == true )
             printf("Yes");
         else
             printf("No");
s
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this a typo: `p = readListInter();` ? and definitely no member called `inOrderTraversal` so code does not match reported errors.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to delete that line, inOrderTraversal it's working fine

Comment: Can you copy/paste the error messages?

Comment: Function 'readListInter' could not 
 be resolved

Comment: There is no such function, you have one that could be called by r->readListInter(), perhaps.  isPerfect vs IsPerfectRec is not perfect either.  Get ahead by using a decent text editor that can provide auto-completion.

Comment: It is defined up, now I have another error: ,,error: invalid operands to binary expression ('BinarySearchTree<int>' and 'long')" at the line ,,input= BinarySearchTree(x);"

Comment: "root->*left_son" -- what??? What is that supposed to mean, here?

Comment: Since when do you have a constructor that takes a single argument? Constructors return the constructed object, not the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to write `BinarySearchTree<T>` instead of `BinarySearchTree` as a datatype in those functions.